# What is the standard notation for “for some number”?

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

While $\forall$ means “for all”, there seems to be no symbol which means “for some.” What would be the correct way to generally notate this?

Comment: Probably $\exists$, most often read as "exists"? But a bit of context to explain exactly what you mean by "for some" would help.

Comment: See [Quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))

Comment: @Ricky: All uses I have seen were $\exists!$, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes that's a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"For some number n in the naturals, n=10" can be written as $$\exists n\in\mathbb N(n=10)$$

This doesn't specify whether that's the only number equal to 10, but it does specify that there is at least one such number in the set of all natural numbers. Does that answer your question?